# return to original page after update in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a asp.net MVC to select 10 rows data from a table if certain column is null, and allow update that column.
every time after i update it, I want it to return to the original 10 that was displayed, instead of doing a new select. because i want it to allow me to see if the update was successful.

Here is my current code.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DBUpdateTool.Models;

namespace DBUpdateTool.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private dtsdbEntities _db = new dtsdbEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.IPR_CompanyGen.Where(c => c.ACCOUNT_ID == null).Take(10).ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var CompanyToEdit = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen where (m.CompanyID.Equals(id.ToString())) select m).First();
            return View(CompanyToEdit);
        }


        // GET: Home/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CompanyID,CompanyName,Address1,Address2,Address3,City,StateProvinceCode,PostalCode,CountryCode,Region,PhoneNumber,URL,PrimaryCompanyType, DominantCompanyStyle,   DominantCompanyOrientation, Buy_side,   Sell_side,  Strategic,  EqPortfolioTurnover,    ReportedEquityAssets,   Status, LastModifiedDate,   ACCOUNT_ID, CRM_Comments")] IPR_CompanyGen CompanyToEdit)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var OriginalCompany = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen where (m.CompanyID.Equals(CompanyToEdit.CompanyID.ToString())) select m).First();
                OriginalCompany.ACCOUNT_ID = CompanyToEdit.ACCOUNT_ID;

                _db.Entry(OriginalCompany).CurrentValues.SetValues(OriginalCompany);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                 return View(OriginalCompany);
            }
            return View();
        }



    }

    internal class DBEntities
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: why are your return RedirectToAction("Index"); while you want to go View(CompanyToEdit).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return RedirectToAction("Index");` put

`return View(OriginalCompany);`

Comment: Because i wanted to go back to the original page with 10 rows on the page, but show the latest status (account_id) of all those 10 companies. Your approach stays at the the edit form for that 1 company only, but this shall be okay for me too.

Comment: However, instead of using `return View(CompanyToEdit);`, I think it should be ` return View(OriginalCompany)`? Otherwise companyname shows empty in the form

Comment: using return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); will return the index page which will have all updated values, `return View(OriginalCompany);` will return the updated values for this Id. Which do you want?

Comment: I prefer the index page. But `RedirectToAction(nameof(Index))`  didnt show me the index page with all updated value. It stays at the edit window. Also remmeber my index page automatically display 10 random companies, that don't have values. But when i return back to it I dont want it to get another 10 companies, instead i want to show the original 10 companies

Comment: In that case, you need to change the `return View();` in the index method, because that is set to return `Account_ID == null`, so change that

Comment: okay, so I guess I need another button called refresh, to replace the current index method? eg after this 10 rows are done, I want another 10 random rows to display. I will click the refresh button

Comment: You could also add an if statement in the index method, and `if (...){ return View(whatever) }'

Comment: but again, back to the question, what is the format to see the original 10 rows with updated value?